# move a running PHP instance from one server to another

Tags: php, parallel-processing, distributed-system

Imagine a request comes to Nginx, then we process the request in PHP .... suddenly while execution of PHP is running, we don't have more resources in the server , so we need to process that PHP code on other server with more resources.

How can we "move" the complete PHP process to another server with more resources and then send back the result ?

this is like having a distributed php infrastructure, behaving in a dynamic way.

how can we achieve something like this?

Comment: Sounds more suitable to setting up a load balancer which picks the right server for the request in the first place.

Comment: I may be wrong, but don't think we have the technology to move an arbitrary process in an arbitrary execution state to a different machine. A process uses processor registries and cache, primary memory, files, network connections...

Comment: You can't move processes between servers. However, with a load balancer and Apache proxying or varnish, you can redirect requests before they actually start. A load balancer can balance requests between multiple servers based on number of requests, while proxying can route certain requests (such as admin or POST requests) to a specific server.

Comment: You could use a queue server like Rabbit. After queuing you can quit the PHP process. Then consume the queue on other server(s). The problem on that is you may or shall not answer in time. If you don't want a queue server you could utilize a Database i.e. mySQL instead.

Comment: Presumably, if process `n` runs out of resources, then process `n+1` will also be out of resources, as well as `n+2`, `n+3` and so on, so your server is actually failing?

Comment: If you are specifically talking about just a process using more memory than the maximum you'll allocated for PHP processes in your config, OOM is not a catchable error (you can do things, but you are in shutdown mode). To get around this, register your work as a "task" in a queue somehow has @MarkusZeller said, and then run that as a secondary process. If that process crashes, your primary will still be alive and you can at least "do something", like move the task to your more expensive task running server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment I found out these 2 paths:

CRIU
https://criu.org/Main_Page

MOSIX
https://mosix.cs.huji.ac.il/txt_distributions.html

or

Dockerizing the app ... and move the docker container from one machine to another.

(Applies the same to virtual machines)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a load balancer. This is a separate server that proxies (forwards) the request to an available PHP server. If this is something you actually need (and most don't) you can instead use a containerised service with auto-scaling to take care of it for you.